# R Shiny: embed javascript to customize the output

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to embed javascript and css code to customize `textOutput` in shiny R like this: https://jsfiddle.net/JoannaMelon/h4nqj03p/10/

But the js code part seems not link to `textOutput` in shiny R.

Here is my minimal reproducible demo:

```
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI(
fluidPage(
  tags$div(
        class = 'box-body-wrapper',
      tags$div(
        class = 'box-body elipsis',
        textOutput("text1") 
      )
      ),

  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
.box-body div, .box-body h3, .box-body h6 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 .25em;
  font-size: 1em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.box-body {
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  display: inline;
}
.box-body.elipsis {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.expand-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(0, 147, 211);
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
"
)) ),

tags$head(
tags$script(HTML(
"
const boxBodyWrapper = document.querySelector('.box-body-wrapper');
const boxBody = document.querySelector('.box-body');
const myWidth = document.querySelector('#text1');

if (myWidth.offsetWidth > boxBody.offsetWidth) {
  boxBody.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  const expandButton = document.createElement('div');
  expandButton.innerText='Show All';
  expandButton.classList.add('expand-button');
  boxBodyWrapper.appendChild(expandButton);
  let expandedButton = false;
  expandButton.addEventListener(
    'click', () => {
      boxBody.classList.toggle('elipsis');
      expandedButton = !expandedButton;
      (expandedButton) ? (expandButton.innerText='Show Less') : (expandButton.innerText='Show All');
    }
  )
}
"
)) )

    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session){

    output$text1 <- renderText({
      paste("He determined to drop 
his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and 
fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable, 
and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.")
    })
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This procudes the JS error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null at (index):46`

Comment: Thanks @ThomasFuchs, does it mean that I need to define an `offsetWidth` for shiny app? I am a beginner in HTML world so it would be a great help if you can provide some guidance for problem solving. Thanks again! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the text is created in the server side of your app, the text is added after the page is loaded. Then, the problem with the JavaScript code is that it is executed before the `textOutput` render the text in the page. Therefore, the element with an id `text1` doesn't exists and that is why the property `offsetWidth` doesn't exists either. The simplest solution is to execute the JavaScript code a little bit later. You can do it by enclosing the code in `setTimeout` function with a specific delay in milliseconds. Below is your code modified to use the `setTimeout` functions with 500 milliseconds, maybe you can change it to your specific problem.

```R
shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    fluidPage(
      tags$div(class = 'box-body-wrapper', 
        tags$div(class = 'box-body elipsis',
            textOutput("text1") 
        )
      ),
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
        .box-body div, .box-body h3, .box-body h6 {
          display: inline;
          padding: 0 .25em;
          font-size: 1em;
          vertical-align: bottom;
        }
        .box-body {
          width: calc(100% - 70px);
          display: inline;
        }
        .box-body.elipsis {
          display: inline-block;
          white-space: nowrap; 
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }

        .expand-button {
          cursor: pointer;
          color: rgb(0, 147, 211);
          margin: 0;
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: top;
        }
      "
      ))),
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML(
        "setTimeout(function(){
          var boxBodyWrapper = document.querySelector('.box-body-wrapper');
          var boxBody = document.querySelector('.box-body');
          var myWidth = document.querySelector('#text1');

          if (myWidth.offsetWidth > boxBody.offsetWidth) {
            boxBody.style.overflow = 'hidden';
            var expandButton = document.createElement('div');
            expandButton.innerText='Show All';
            expandButton.classList.add('expand-button');
            boxBodyWrapper.appendChild(expandButton);
            let expandedButton = false;
            expandButton.addEventListener(
              'click', () => {
                boxBody.classList.toggle('elipsis');
                expandedButton = !expandedButton;
                (expandedButton) ? (expandButton.innerText='Show Less') : (expandButton.innerText='Show All');
              }
            )
          }
        }, 500)"
      )))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$text1 <- renderText({
      paste("He determined to drop 
            his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and 
            fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable, 
            and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.")
    })
  }
)
```

You could also use the `shinyjs` library to execute the JavaScript code just after the creating of other `textOutput`.